# ModelMapper Not Mapping

Tags: enums, modelmapper

When I try to map String in a source to Integer in Destination via Enum. ModelMapper fails.

Source

```
public class Request {
    private String classification;
}
```

Destination

```
public class DTO {
    private Integer classification;
}
```

Mapping between String and Integer is defined in ENUM

```
public enum Classification {

POWER(3, "Power"),
PERFORMANCE(4, "Performance"),
TASK(13, "Task");

private final Integer code;
private final String  name;

ProblemClassification(final int code, final String name) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public static Integer getCodeByName(String name) {
    Optional<Classification> classification = Arrays.asList(Classification.values()).stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            .findFirst();
    return classification.isPresent() ? classification.get().getCode() : null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `Converter` there:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
Converter<String, Integer> classificationConverter =
                ctx -> ctx.getSource() == null ? null : Classification.getCodeByName(ctx.getSource());
modelMapper.typeMap(Request.class, DTO.class)
                .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(classificationConverter).map(Request::getClassification, DTO::setClassification));
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote this converter and it works but a problem is, there are two similar fields. The second field is Priority and If I map Priority to Another Enum. this also uses the same converter and mapping does not happen properly.

Comment: @Jags, define a new `Converter` for Priority enum.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this wasn't working as expected but Yes its working now. Just uploaded this simple project in git, So this may help others. https://github.com/hsjagadeesh/LearningModelMapper